# Fragment caching based on session id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to use fragment cache on specific forms (new action) based on session id in ruby on rails. These forms should expire at session destroy or any changes on records used in these forms.

**Problem:**
These form content changes based on user type, like certain fields are shown for certain user types. 
When i cache the form, it shows same form for all user type logins.

New.html.erb

```
<% cache 'procedure_form_cache', skip_digest: true do %>
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <h3>Procedure</h3>
        <%= render 'form', procedure: @procedure %>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

Procedure.rb

```
class Procedure < ApplicationRecord
  def expire_cache             
         ActionController::Base.new.expire_fragment('procedure_form_cache')
  end
end
```

I expect the fragment cache based on session id in forms

Comment: maybe you can try using a cache key based on sesion id, something like `<% cache "procedure_form_cache_#{session[:id]}" ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% cache [session.id, @procedure.updated_at] do %>
    <div class="container">
        <hr>
        <h3>Procedure</h3>
        <%= render 'form', procedure: @procedure %>
    </div>
<%end%>
```

should do the trick, the cache will be updated if the session id changes or any change on `@procedure`.